# how to reverse command Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Example 1: `sudo sed -i "s/#user = "root"/user = "$(id -un)"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`
Example 2: `sudo sed -i "s/#group = "root"/group = "$(id -gn)"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

I search with google but no answers

Comment: What output did this give, it shouldn't work without escaping the middle " " (ie the quotes). Note that `sed -i "s/A/B/g" /path/to/file` takes all A in the given file and replaces it with B, to revert you can often switch the command to say s/B/A/g. Or you can type `id -un && id -gn` in your shell and look in the file with an editor for those lines starting "user = " and "group = " and ending in the numbers it gives you.

Comment: Shellcheck gives useful hints: https://pastebin.com/gJ021KLH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't leave this as a comment because I have too few points.

*This is not Ubuntu-specific and can be used on other distributions as well*

For example one:

```
sudo sed -i "s/user = "$(id -un)"/user = "root"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
```

For example two:

```
sudo sed -i "s/group = "$(id -gn)"/group = "root"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
```

Comment: Ok. I try when i get home.. thanks